# Unable to free a pointer from within a function

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Following assert doesn't fails, though it should fail according to my understanding. Please correct me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void custom_free(int **temp){
      free(*temp);     
}

int main(){
    int *ptr = malloc(1024);
    custom_free(&ptr);
    assert(ptr); // doesn't fails ..why?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "free a pointer", but you can free the memory referenced by a pointer. And that's what `free` does: it doesn't modify the pointer, it only does something with what the pointer points to.

Your issue has nothing to do with whether the `free` call is done in a function or not. Try adding

```
*temp = 0;
```

after your `free` call to enforce that you get a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks! that worked, but then what does it mean to free the memory if the pointer still points to the same address?

Comment: @user2901020: "Freeing" memory means removing a memory block (the first byte of which, i.e. the start of the block, is referenced by the pointer you pass to `free`) from the internal memory bookkeeping - the memory no longer counts as `allocated`. `free` does *not* change the value of the pointer, and it also doesn't necessarily set the memory which was released to some specific value (e.g. all null bytes or so).

Answer (score 3):

Calling `free` doesn't change the value of a pointer.  If you want to `NULL` freed memory you'll have to do it yourself

```
void custom_free(int **temp){
      free(*temp); 
      *temp = NULL;
}
```